# Arithmetic Quiz On VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner and need help with a school project. I'm trying to get the scores to show from highest to lowest and the average score. How can I do this? My current code is:

```
Dim filename As String
        Dim numberofrecords As Short
        Dim countofloop As Short
        Dim one, two, three As Short

        filename = "N:\Class1.dat"
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(OneStudentScore))
        numberofrecords = LOF(1) / Len(OneStudentScore)

        countofloop = 0

        Dim scores(numberofrecords) As Integer
        Dim names(numberofrecords) As String

        Do While (Not EOF(1))
            FileGet(1, OneStudentScore)

            one = OneStudentScore.score1
            two = OneStudentScore.score2
            three = OneStudentScore.score3

            names(countofloop) = OneStudentScore.Name

            If one > two Then
                If one > three Then
                    '1st score is the biggest
                    scores(countofloop) = one
                Else
                    scores(countofloop) = three
                End If
            Else
                If two > three Then
                    scores(countofloop) = two
                Else
                    scores(countofloop) = three
                End If
            End If

            countofloop = countofloop + 1
        Loop

        'sort array into score order
        Array.Sort(scores, names)

        'this allows the arrays to be in descending order - highest first 
        Array.Reverse(scores)
        Array.Reverse(names)

        Dim displayeditem As String
        lstClass1.Items.Clear()

        'display the arrays in a list box
        For i = 0 To countofloop
            displayeditem = names(i) & " " & scores(i)
            lstClass1.Items.Add(displayeditem)

            FileClose()
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run the code but it would appear that you are properly sorting the array to go from highest to lowest. If you just need the average then it should just be a matter of adding up the elements in the `scores` array and dividing by the number of elements. Something like:

```
Dim total As Integer = 0
Dim numScores As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To scores.Length - 1
    total += scores(i)
    numScores += 1
Next

Dim average As Integer
average = total / numScores
```

Comment: Hello mate. Well, with the highest scores, it randomly appears with a zero under the name in the listview when I click the highest to lowest button and the scores aren't displayed in the correct columns.